# lli is generating run-time error for clang++ generated IR while the generated executable is not generating run-time error for c++ source code

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-c++-api, lli

I am trying to generate a bit code from a c++ source code and running through the just-in-time compiler. When I compile through the clang++ and generate binary executable it runs perfectly but when I generated the bitcode and tried running through the JIT with lli command it generates run-time error. Could you please help me understanding what's going on.

For example: Let example.cpp contains the following code:

```
 #include <iostream>

 int main(){
    std::cout << "\nHello World!";
    return 0;
 }
```

I am using the following command to generate executable which runs perfectly fine.

```
clang++ example.cpp
```

I am using the following command to generate the bitcode:

```
clang++ -S -emit-llvm example.cpp
```

And then running through the JIT using the following command which generates run-time error:

```
lli example.ll
```

I am getting the following access violation error:

```
Stack dump:
0.      Program arguments: lli example.ll
#0 0x00000000025fd9af llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) /home/xpc/llvm/llvm-project1/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:564:0
#1 0x00000000025fda42 PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) /home/xpc/llvm/llvm-project1/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:625:0
#2 0x00000000025fb7ca llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() /home/xpc/llvm/llvm-project1/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Support/Signals.cpp:68:0
#3 0x00000000025fd329 SignalHandler(int) /home/xpc/llvm/llvm-project1/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:406:0
#4 0x00007fa75dbdc390 __restore_rt (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x11390)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what's happening, but with a bit of testing seems that the issue is C++ (C code produces no issue, and as does C like C++ generated by `clang++`). Not sure if `lli` expects some arguments to support C++ bytecode(explicitly specifying external shared objects) or what. Unfortunately I couldn't find example of C++ bytecode compilation/use, but good luck with your search

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling with `clang++ -S -emit-llvm -fno-use-cxa-atexit example.cpp`.

I think it's probably because clang and gcc try prefer `__cxa_atexit` to
`atexit` by default (these are functions used for cleaning up global objects when a program exits). Meaning you'll get a linker error if your libc implementation doesn't support the former. So disabling the `use-cxa-atexit` flag should work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's a library linking issue. Try to use the followings:

1. Try `lli -force-interpreter example.ll` instead of `lli example.ll`
   When JIT can't work properly, you should try interpreter.
   if the following err:
   `LLVM ERROR: Could not resolve external global address: __dso_handle`
   Then add `-fno-use-cxa-atexit` to clang flags, reasons from [[LLVMdev] MCJIT/interpreter and iostream](https://groups.google.com/g/llvm-dev/c/WUMwGnaaaSc).
2. After retry `lli -force-interpreter example.ll` if still have some errors like `LLVM ERROR: Tried to execute an unknown external function: ...`. Then you should recompile LLVM with ffi library enabled. See the following for reasons: [Advice on Packaging LLVM¶](https://llvm.org/docs/Packaging.html)
    and [[LLVMdev] lli --force-interpreter does not find external function](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2009-November/027209.html)